# How to define type of a property at runtime in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, types

In Winform application I have a class with 2 properties and I want the user to be able to choose the type of those properties.

This is what I made so far:

Class with the properties:

```
static public class DataGridColumnData
{
    public static object SearchColumn { get; set; }
    public static object ResultColumn { get; set; }
}
```

And the user can choose the type of the properties using a Combobox with DropDownList Style which has values like

```
System.String
System.Double
System.Int32
System.Boolean
System.DateTime
```

Is there a way to make those properties to be types the ones that user chooses?

Comment: How do you want to use this after the user selects a type?  Do you want to filter some data with it?

Comment: Ditto Wouter's comment - those types are most useful at compile time. At runtime it's not going to make too much difference. That said, you could always define a generic wrapper class `DataGridColumnData` that inherits from the other class and wraps the accessors with types accessors, and then new instances of that. But I'm not sure what you'd do with those that you couldn't do with the object version.

Comment: Those properties will be used to create Columns in DataGridView.Also the data extracted from Database will be stored in the List that is bound to the DataGridView, so I might use the properties to convert database data to the types the user selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to make the properties strongly typed in runtime using generics, but I am not sure how useful it is. Here is a solution either way:

Create an interface that is not strongly typed to facilitate interaction with the object:

```
public interface IDataGridColumnData
{
    object SearchColumnAsObject { get; set; }
    object ResultColumnAsObject { get; set; }
}
```

Create generic class that allows for the creation of strongly typed versions at runtime (and in code as well, of course), and that implements the interface:

```
public class DataGridColumnData<TSearch, TResult> : IDataGridColumnData
{
    public TSearch SearchColumn { get; set; }
    public static TResult ResultColumn { get; set; }
    public object SearchColumnAsObject
    {
        get { return SearchColumn; }
        set { SearchColumn = (TSearch)value; }
    }
    public object ResultColumnAsObject
    {
        get { return ResultColumn; }
        set { ResultColumn = (TResult)value; }
    }
}
```

Create a factory method that will manufacture strongly typed versions of the class, returning it as the object-typed interface:

```
private static IDataGridColumnData GetDataGridColumnData(
    Type searchType, Type resultType)
{
    var typedColumnDataType = typeof(DataGridColumnData<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(new[] { searchType, resultType });
    return (IDataGridColumnData)Activator.CreateInstance(typedColumnDataType);
}
```

...and put it to use:

```
IDataGridColumnData instance = GetDataGridColumnData(
    Type.GetType("System.Int32"),
    Type.GetType("System.String"));

// use the properties
instance.SearchColumnAsObject = 42; // works well
instance.SearchColumnAsObject = "42"; // throws exception
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make your class generic:

```
static public class DataGridColumnData<T>
{ 
    public static T SearchColumn { get; set; } 
    public static T ResultColumn { get; set; } 
}
```

Then, in your code, you can create a class of the desired type:

```
object myDataGridColumnData;
if (userSelection == "String") {
    myDataGridColumnData = new DataGridColumnData<string>();
} else if (userSelection == "Double") {
    myDataGridColumnData = new DataGridColumnData<double>();
} ...
```

Note that, technically, `DataGridColumnData<string>` is a completely different type than `DataGridColumnData<int>`, so `object` is the only common supertype. Thus, to be able to access the values of `myDataGridColumnData` in code, you might need to use a `dynamic` variable or (prefered) use some common interface or base class that returns the values typed as objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, ther is not. A class is statically compiled. No wy to change the property for a static class at runtime.

You can create a subclass nd override it, via bytecode emission, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is` keyword

```
if (x.SearchColumn is Double)
{
}
```

See also MSDN: [Is (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Comment: He wants to set the type of the SearchColumn, not check what type it is.

Comment: Oh, I thought the OP just wanted to box any object into the property and later decide what type the object was. I assumed the OP has hard coded the type `object` as an "accepts all" kind of Type. A box that fits anything, but when you open it you don't know what type the object inside was.